# Sampling Substeps in fluid-simulations

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm new to Blender an i'm learning something about fluid-simulations. In the physics settings of the flow-object is a setting called: "Sampling Substeps".

I have played arround with the value to find out, what it does. But in my eyes, nothing is changing when changing the Value.

So What does it do?

Have a nice day:)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tooltip suggests that it's useful for fast moving flows. The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/flow.html) is more precise, and indicates it's mostly useful for fast moving *sources* - so you won't see any effect unless your source is moving.

[image]

Comment: Oh Thanks! That makes sense:)